# passing parameter from html to javascript in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a javascript function to which I should pass a parameter.This parameter should be retrieved from html like this

```
<tr  ng-repeat="restaurant in accounts.selectedRestaurants">
  <td >{{restaurant}}</td>
   <td>{{accounts.findAllAccountsByRestaurant(restaurant)}}</td>
</tr>
```

my function is accounts.findAllAccountsByRestaurant() and the parameter is restaurant, which is retrieved from ng-repeat.How can I pass this parameter to the function?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't alter your question after it has been answered. Ask a *new* question for new problems.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
<tr  ng-repeat="restaurant in accounts.selectedRestaurants">
  <td >{{restaurant}}</td>
   <td>{{accounts.findAllAccountsByRestaurant(restaurant)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.accounts.findAllAccountsByRestaurant = function(restaurant) {   return alert(restaurant); };
```

Comment: Yes but I don't need a button in a td

Comment: So you want to loop over the array and call the function for each object?

Comment: yes exactely but I should call the function inside the td not in a button

Comment: is your function defined on the $scope? if so your code should work

Comment: Thank you for your response.It was very helpful for me.I have one small issue that I don't know its origin. I will display  it in the main post.

Comment: I have posted it in the main post above

Comment: Do you have an idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
<td ng-init="Y(product)">{{product}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.products=[11,22,33];
$scope.Y= function(ar)
 {
 alert(ar);
 };
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined your scope correctly, everything should work as it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/jpwup7Lb/5/

```
$scope.accounts={
    selectedRestaurants:
        ["one","two","three"],
    findAllAccountsByRestaurant:function(restaraunt){
        return "here's all accounts for "+restaraunt;
    }
}
```